# Unable to "click" in recent webdriver release on FireFox

Tags: firefox, click, webdriver, intermittent

I am facing intermittent issue in Clicking on a button or a hyperlink on Firefox.
I am using webdriver version 2.27 and FF17.

The buttons are simple html button -

```
<input class="btn" type="button" title="AddP" onclick="navigateToUrl('/p/tyy/SelectSearch?addTo=006y67&retURL=%2F00999yu2Boy9','MM_LIST','addP');" name="addP" value="Add P">
```

I use locator as : `name=addP`

For hyperlinks I use locator as : `link=hyperlinktext`

The Click will not fail with any exception, it will simply highlight the button or link, but not perform the actual click.

The frequency of failure is once in 3 times.

Thanks
Sky

Comment: Firstly upgrade Selenium to v2.28. Would also be worth downgrading Firefox to an earlier version (16 would be fine), just to see if the issue lies within what version of Firefox you have.

Comment: @Arran - I was working with FF16, because of issue upgraded and tried in FF17. Will try to use Sel 2.28 now. Thanks.

Comment: @Arran Sel v2.28 doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to at least Selenium 2.28.  There were some bugs for Firefox 17 before that.

Comment: I tried 2.28, it doesn't help. Same click is working for multiple test cases, but failing in one. No exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i found :

**[Issue 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709185/selenium-2-webdriver-not-able-to-find-link):** I was using `By.linkText("test test").click` which should have been `By.partialLinkText("test test").click` . Thanks to stackoverflow for the answer.

**Issue 2:** I rewrote the css locators for failed button to start from class of some parent above.
For e.g. instead of

> css=input[name='j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:j_id4']

I am now using

> css=.individualPalette input[name='j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:j_id4']

And it works all the time. I am not sure why??

I am still to rerun my scripts couple of more times to be sure these helps.